# Django modelformset_factory to update the existing images

Tags: django, django-forms

```
class ProductImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductImage
        fields = ['product', 'original', 'caption']
        # use ImageInput widget to create HTML displaying the
        # actual uploaded image and providing the upload dialog
        # when clicking on the actual image.
        widgets = {
            'original': ImageInput(),
        }

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # We infer the display order of the image based on the order of the
        # image fields within the formset.
        kwargs['commit'] = False
        obj = super(ProductImageForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        obj.display_order = self.get_display_order()
        obj.save()
        return obj

    def get_display_order(self):
        if self.prefix:
            return self.prefix.split('-').pop()
        else:
            return 1
```

I am using django modelformset_factory to insert images into database and also update the images.The problem now is that image is inserted into database instead of updation while using modelformset_factory.Following below are the my code.Please help me to update other than saving

```
            ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(ProductImage,
                                     form=ProductImageForm, extra=0, can_delete=True)
            formset = ImageFormSet(self.request.POST or None, self.request.FILES or None, data)
            if formset.is_valid():
                try:
                    instances = formset.save(commit=False)
                    for instance in instances:
                        instance.save()
                except Exception as e:
                    pass
            else:
                err = formset.errors
                raise error_message(err)
```

Comment: Please show your template.

Comment: @ Alasdair I am using django rest framework.My post parameters are these with management form data like these form-TOTAL_FORMS.Post parameters seems to be ok,because it get saved.Is it need to send some other POST parameters for updation instead of saving

Comment: In that case there is probably something  wrong with your post data. I recommend getting the view to work with a template first. Then, you can check the post data and fix the request made by rest framework.

Comment: Note that you're not handling delete objects properly (see [the docs])(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/#can-delete). You're not doing anything special when saving the instances, so would be easier to save with `commit=True`, then you don't have to loop.

Comment: The problem could also be in you `ProductImageForm`, which you haven't shown, but I think that's unlikely. I still think the best thing is to get the view working with a template, then switch to rest framework.

Comment: I have included ProductImageForm at the top.The product image get saved as new image instead of updating the old image.Is any thing like form(instance=object,data) for updation in the case of forms exist for formset that make it updating instead of saving

Comment: The formset should update existing objects by default. If it doesn't then you are either doing something odd in your form/view, or posting incorrect data. Unless somebody can spot the problem, you'll have to debug this yourself. The easiest thing is to start with as simple a view as possible (e.g. no custom form, submit from template instead of rest framework), then add functionality gradually. Then it's easier to tell what's causing the problem. The form's `save` method and `ImageInput` both look unusual, so I would try removing it.

Comment: Also, what is `data` in `ImageFormSet(self.request.POST or None, self.request.FILES or None, data)`? Try removing that as well.

Comment: At first big thanks for helping me.Actually my image updation is similar to that django oscar product image updation.To make it recognize as edit,i also give form-0-id for which image to update as similar to django oscar.but still not working